# Making Generic Form parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a thread class. The class simply creates a thread of the new form to open

```
class Threading
{
    private static int sendingForm;
    public void StartThread()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
        t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }

    public static void ThreadProc()
    {
        switch (sendingForm)
        {
            case 1:
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new MainForm());
                break;
            case 2:
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new ReportPicker());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is simple, I am just practicing using threads. I don't want to do it in each form, so I tried recycling a bit of code by making it in  a class. As you can see, the way I detect the form I want to go is by sending a number depending on the form I want to go. Based on that number will be the form the thread runs. I want to better this if it's possible. I was thinking of maybe a way to send as parameter the form that I want to go to, but since each form is it's own type, I can't find a way to do it. As a matter of fact, I don't know if it's possible to do. So, I ask here if you can help me make my code better. It doesn't matter if it's by the method I'm asking, just to recycle as much code as possible. This is for the sake of learning to use threads. Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: When you have a winform application you want to have **just one UI thread**.  While creating multiple UI threads is *possible*, it's just really messy, confusing, hard to maintain, etc.  If you want to learn more about threading that's great, but I'd just do non-UI stuff in your new threads while you're learning about them (and really, forever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you want to cut out the redundancy and duplication in ThreadProc. That's good! Here is a possible solution:

```
public static void ThreadProc<TForm>() where TForm : Form, new()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new TForm());
}

new System.Threading.Thread(() => ThreadProc<MainForm>())
```

Or, reflection-based:

```
public static void ThreadProc(Type formType)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run((Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType));
}

new System.Threading.Thread(() => ThreadProc(typeof(MainForm)))
```

Or, caller-injected:

```
public static void ThreadProc(Form form)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form);
}

new System.Threading.Thread(() => ThreadProc(new MainForm()))
```

Note, that the caller has to change in all cases to adopt the new calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

There are some golden rules when using threads.

1. Data processed by the thread should be given as parameters. (sendingForm is the problem here.)
2. UI should never be multi threaded, use Invoke or BeginInvoke to do UI-stuff.
3. Lock shared resources if they are modified while used by threads.
4. Only use threads if it takes too long in the UI or if there is no UI.

But I recommend that you look at Task and BackgroundWorkerThread rather than doing some threading your self the first couple of times.

Comment: Is BackgroundWorkerThread a class or did you just mean BackgroundWorker thread?

Comment: @IanO'Brien I think Casperah meant BackgroundWorker class that simplifies threading in UI environment. It has built-in processing of cross-thread UI event handling.